# What's the best way to update several (200k)rows in a database?

Tags: mysql

I've got a database that I need to update a column in some rows. I've got the data from my logs and I wrote php script that processes each log and extracts the data in to a file with an update for each record that needs it.

I broke it down in to each month but running this is taking forever. Is there a better way to do it?

The file is basically a .sql file filled with 205k rows of

```sql
update table set ended_at = '2019-01-31 23:59:30' where uuid = '304ad6ea-b949-42f5-96a0-a7a550e6126d';
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Please add table description for table `table`.  After that the reader here will know if you have an index on the field `uuid`, or not.  When you do not hove an index on that field, it might be a good idea to create one.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the schema is poorly designed if you have 205K rows with the identical `uuid`.

Furthermore, if you need all of them to have the same `ended_at` value, then there should be some other table that has, for example, *one* row with `uuid` and `ended_at`.  The `JOIN` to get the data during a `SELECT` will be more than compensated for by having removed `ended_at` from the big table.

Perhaps I am being overly critical.  If so, please provide some more insight into what the columns mean, and where the uuids come from, etc.

The best way to update "many" rows in a "huge" table is to walk through the table by the `PRIMARY KEY`, and update a thousand rows at a time.  More details on chunking:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: That was an example of the rows. It's not litterally 205k of the same row.

Answer (score 0):

best technique to update with other table using inner join

UPDATE T1 SET    T1.dept_ID  = T2.dept_ID
    FROM tblPro     T1 JOIN (othertable)   t2    ON T2.Doc_ID  = T1.DOC_ID

IF YOU dont have other table just creat view or function and then join it with T1 and update as you like
Tariq Jamil